# Called script file in document.ready

Tags: jquery

I have some code in .js file. If I load js file first then js code is not getting work since html page is render afterowrds. So is there any way that I can called js file inside document.ready function?

Comment: Well, yes, you can write whatever code you like in the document.ready handler.  Did you try?  Is something not working?  Maybe you don't need the document.ready handler at all and just need to include a script in the footer of the page instead of the header?  What exactly isn't working?

Comment: post some code please...

Comment: I have code like 

$('ready_access').hide();

But in the tpl where I called ready_access  class for checkboxes is not work. It should expect to hide. But when i executed the code in browser console it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert in your .js file.

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
         // your code
});
```

And insert into html up anywhere.
Your code will be executed only after the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Do you call you JS file at the end of your html file ? Otherwise you can insert a document ready function inside your JS file.

Comment: I called js first and then load tpl contents

Comment: The JS code should always be executed at the end of your file so that the user can start reading the page even if the code is long to execute